# Is there any way to use reactive cassandra repository with Pageable in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-webflux, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to use `ReactiveCassandraRepository` interface for my repository. When I tried to add `findAll` method like this:

```
public interface MatchRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<Match, UUID> {
    Flux<Match> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

I got this error message:

```
Error creating bean with name 'matchRepository' defined in MatchRepository defined in 
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories declared on CassandraReactiveRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableReactiveCassandraRepositoriesConfiguration: 

Could not create query for public abstract reactor.core.publisher.Flux 
MatchRepository.findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable); 
Reason: No property 'findAll' found for type 'Match'
```

How can I implement reactive cassandra repository with Pageable in Spring Boot? Is there any documentation for this?

Answer (score 1):

### Paging and Reactive

Spring Boot Data Cassandra does not provide any paging feature in reactive.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/reactive/package-summary.html

- In synchronous you are waiting to load a page and get back as a result set.
- In Asynchronous you have a callback per page when the page is loaded.

In both cases you triggerload and next page fetching when you exhaust the result set.

In Reactive you get a callback/event for every single record as a stream/flux of records, as such there is no start nor end, and the notion of page has no sense.

### Possible Solution

Now to get a subset of items in a table let's say items from 15 to 25 in 100 elements there is a trick call `limit()` but you will have to work with the `Flux<>`. You may have to access `CassandraOperations`

```java
int offset=15;
int pageSize=10;
ReactiveResultSet rs = cqlSession.executeReactive(bound);
Flux<ReactiveRow> myPage = Flux.from(rs).skip(offset).take(pageSize);
```

### More advice

- Never ever, ever, do a `findAll()` in Cassandra table. Cassandra is meant to store billions of records. You are doing a full scan of the table (VERY SLOW) and you will probably never be able to process that in memory.
- In Cassandra, the design of the table is based on the query/request pattern and there is always a where clause. The where clause will determine how you partitioned your table.